# Can I convert a string with space using totitle?

Tags: tcl, uppercase

The Tcl documentation is clear on how to use [`string totitle`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M54):

> Returns a value equal to *string* except that the first character in
>   *string* is converted to its Unicode title case variant (or upper case
>   if there is no title case variant) **and the rest of the string is
>   converted to lower case**.

Is there a workaround or method that will convert a string with spaces (the first letter of each word would be upper case)?

For example in `Python`:

```
intro : str = "hello world".title()
print(intro) # Will print Hello World, notice the capital H and W.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donal gave you an answer but there is a package that allows you to do what you want [textutil::string](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_string.md) from [Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/toc.md)

```
package require textutil::string
puts [::textutil::string::capEachWord "hello world"] 
> Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

In Tcl 8.7, the absolutely most canonical way of doing this is to use `regsub` with the `-command` option to apply `string totitle` to the substrings you want to alter:

```
set str "hello world"
# Very simple RE: (greedy) sequence of word characters
set tcstr [regsub -all -command {\w+} $str {string totitle}]
puts $tcstr
```

In earlier versions of Tcl, you don't have that option so you need a two stage transformation:

```
set tcstr [subst [regsub -all {\w+} $str {[string totitle &]}]]
```

The problem with this is that it will below up if the input string has certain Tcl metacharacters in it; it *is* possible to fix this, but it's horrible to do; I added the `-command` option to `regsub` precisely because I was fed up of having to do a multi-stage substitute just to make a string I could feed through `subst`. Here's the safe version (the input stage could also be done with `string map`):

```
set tcstr [subst [regsub -all {\w+} [regsub -all {[][$\\]} $str {\\&}] {[string totitle &]}]]
```

It gets really complicated (well, at least quite non-obvious) when you want to actually do the replacement on substrings that have been transformed. Which is why it is now possible to circumvent all that mess with `regsub -command` that is careful with word boundaries when doing the replacement command running (because the Tcl C API is actually good at that).